# how to make your controls stick to the same place if language is changed to RTL while app is running MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

AppInfo.RequestedLayoutDirection doesnt update if you change language to RTL while app is running only when its restarted.

i want my app to not change appearance no matter what layout direction the device is , right now everything gets inverted if layout direction is changed, for example : column 0 becomes column 2 or translationX gets completely reversed.

i've tried finding this info through other means like check to see if language has changed, but that one doesnt change either until app is restarted .

is there anyway to get it to give you the updated LayoutDirection without restarting the app? or other ways to make your controls stick to the same place no matter what?

Comment: I know for a fact from Xamarin.Forms, that on both iOS and Android when the user changes the device language, the app will then be restarted by the OS when entering again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set FlowDirection to ContentPage or any control you want to change the directioin:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ControlsRTL75712428.MainPage"
         FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
```

or

```
<VerticalStackLayout FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
```

Then the control will stick to the direction no matter the language changes.

Hope it works for you.